# How do you properly quote a quote as a title?

Tags: creative-writing, style, grammar, quotes

There's this sentence from Marie Kondo’s book, The Life-Changing Magic of Tidying Up: The Japanese Art of Decluttering and Organizing that I want to use as a header/title of my project, and I need help with properly putting quotations around it.

This is the sentence I want to use:

**"Does this spark joy?" If it does, keep it. If not, dispose of it.**

Is this correct?

**"'Does this spark joy?' If it does, keep it. If not, dispose of it."**

Do I put a single quotation in the beginning and then close with double quotation or change the double quotation after the word joy to a single quotation?? I'm not sure how to go about this.
Or do I not even need to put any quotation if it's being treated as a header/title?? I'm not sure......

Please help!!

Thank you!! =)

-L

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Quote" within a quote MLA](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26638/quote-within-a-quote-mla) It doesn't relate specifically to titles but I don't see why quotes within titles would be treated any differently.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! =)))